# How do I delete all data for a family in hbase table?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We have an HBase table with multiple families, and we need to delete all data for a certain family, but leave the rest untouched. We only need to delete the data, and leave the family there, as we will be repopulating the table with new data for that family.
The simplest way seems to be to delete the files associated with that family from the file system (found under ../{table_name}/{some_hash}/{family_name}/).
Are there any side effects to doing this that we should be aware of?
If there are, are there any safer, easy ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safer way would be to  [deleteColumn](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#deleteColumn%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and remove the family completely and then re-add it with [addColumn](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#addColumn%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor%29). Note that you need to disable the table before you make these changes

Comment: I tried "alter 'table_name', 'delete'=>'family_name'", but that doesn't actually delete the data, just alters the schema. If you re-add the family, the data will also appear again unless you delete the files like I detailed in the question.

Comment: right but it is safer to remove the files when HBase doesn't expect them to be part of the table