# How to to delete column family and its store files from an hbase table, and keep the table enabled?

Tags: java, hbase

The java method [deleteColumn](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html#deleteColumn-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName-byte:A-) of the hbase [Admin](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html) class deletes specified column family from specified HBase table. (Despite of its name the method removes the family, not a column - view the [HBASE-1989](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-1989).) In fact the code

```
Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
admin.deleteColumn(tableName, familyByteName);
```

changes the table's schema, but it doesn't delete column family's Store File from a file system. I observe this effect with HBase 1.2.3/1.0.3 in the standalone and in the pseudo distributed modes. The online schema update property in the hbase-site.xml config file is turned on:

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.online.schema.update.enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

I found the only way to remove column family's HFiles via Java API - disable table in front of delete column family:

```
Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
admin.disableTable(tableName);
admin.deleteColumn(tableName, familyByteName);
admin.enableTable(tableName);
```

But that is inappropriate, because the table should be available for reads and writes permanently. So the questions are:

For what reason the deleteColumn() method doesn't delete column family's store files from a file system?

Is it safe to delete these files bypassing HBase API: call 
`admin.deleteColumn(tableName, familyByteName);` at first, and then delete store files via HDFS Java API?

Is it possible to delete column family  from an hbase table, and delete family's store files, and keep the table enabled?

PS: Here is a link to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453948/how-do-i-delete-all-data-for-a-family-in-hbase-table).